# How to avoid gradle task running at configuration phase and make them run at execution phase

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm writting 2 tasks mentioned below which are dependent, but both are running at the time of application build. which I'm trying to avoid, the code goes like this

```
// Get the coverage from sonar qube server for current branch
task getCoverageReport {
        def headers = [Accept: 'application/json']
        def resourcesId = getProjectResourceId()

        if (resourcesId != null) {
            def jsonText = new URL("(sonar instance)/api/resources?metrics=coverage,test_success_density&resource=" + resourcesId)
                    .getText(requestProperties: headers)
            def parsedJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonText)
            if (null != parsedJson) {
                codeCoverage = parsedJson.msr.get(0).get(0).frmt_val
                testCoverage = parsedJson.msr.get(0).get(1).frmt_val
            }
        }
    }


 confluence {

            tasks.findByName("confluence").doFirst {getCoverageReport}

            String confluenceUser = XXXXX
            String confluencePassword = XXXXXX

            authentication new String(confluenceUser + ":" + 
            confluencePassword).bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
            restApiUrl 'some uri'
            spaceKey 'XXXX'
            sslTrustAll true
            pageVariables = ['project.name'   : project.name,
                             'release.version': someversion,
                             'codeCoverage'   : codeCoverage,
                             'testCoverage'   : testCoverage
           ]

            pages {
              page {
                parentTitle 'page title'
                title "title" + project.getProperties().get('version')
                srcFile file('some file location')
                labels = ['Release Report']
              }
            }
          }
```

If noticed I'm trying to call `getCoverageReport` first in `confluence` task.
The problem is these 2 tasks are running at application build time i.e. when I run the command as `gradlew build`.

I went through the document, and got that tasks are running in configuration phase and not at execution phase how should I handle it? to run them at execution phase.

If I try to put the getCoverageReport code in doFirst clause, and run `gradlew confluence` then it does not run getCoverageReport

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: task getCoverageReport <<{ bla bla}
task confluence<<(dependsOn: getCoverageReport){ bla again}

Comment: Thanks Kid101 for your reply but If I try to put task for confluence I get an error as        Cannot add task ':confluence' as a task with that name already exists.